# Type mismatch with existential types inside Option

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm trying to pass a bunch of classes to the `SparkConf.registerKryoClasses` method, which has the following signature:

```
registerKryoClasses: Array[Class[_]]) => SparkConf
```

Since I may or may not have classes that need to be registered, I'm wrapping it in an `Option` and tried this (in a simplified version):

```
class SomeClass(val app: String, val classes: Option[Array[Class[_]]]) {
  val conf = classes match {
    case Some(cs) ⇒ new SparkConf()
      .setAppName(app)
      .registerKryoClasses(cs)
    case None ⇒ new SparkConf()
      .setAppName(app)
  }
  // more stuff
}
```

IntelliJ gives me that there is a type mismatch on `cs` and then lists the expected and actual types. They are the same.

What am I missing here?

Comment: I know this cliche, but have you tried restarting it? I get similar problems on PyCharm and IntelliJ occasionally, and sometimes restarting helps. Other times I have to use a "dumber" IDE to manually compile the code so IntelliJ recognizes that the code is indeed correct.

Comment: Copy pasting this code compiles fine for me.

Comment: Don't trust the errors IntelliJ shows in the editor, check if it actually compiles first.

Comment: Why are you trying to create `SomeClass`, why not define a function for it ?

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh Because a lot more happens after that piece of code and I have to pass the instance around because the rest of the application must 'feed off' the same SparkContext instance details.

Comment: I had invalidated the caches and restarted but somehow IntelliJ kept the information on hand. The code works fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The following works fine for me,

```
def someClass(app: String, classes: Option[Array[Class[Any]]]): SparkConf = {
  val conf = classes match {
    case Some(cs) ⇒ new SparkConf()
      .setAppName(app)
      .registerKryoClasses(cs)
    case None ⇒ new SparkConf()
      .setAppName(app)
    // more stuff
  }

  conf
}

val conf = someClass("lol", Some(Array(classOf[String], classOf[Int])))
//org.apache.spark.SparkConf = org.apache.spark.SparkConf@685d92cf
```